# Can you help simplify this linq?

Tags: c#

```
public List<Order> GetGrainOrders()
{
    var orders = GetOrdersJson();
    orders = orders.Select(o => o)
                   .Where(o => o.LineItems.Any(i => i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")))
                   .ToList();
    orders.ForEach(o => o.LineItems.RemoveAll(i => !i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")));
    return orders;
}
```

Can you help me simplify these linq queries?

Cheers

Comment: What is your definition of "simple"?

Comment: What is the point of `orders.ForEach(o => o.LineItems.RemoveAll(i => !i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")));` when you are selecting only items that contain "GRNS" ?

Comment: `ForEach` and `RemoveAll` are List methods, not LINQ methods. This means the only LINQ expression is `orders.Select(o=>).Where(..).ToList()`. What the point of that `Select()` though?

Comment: @RayaChorbadzhiyska, that line removes specific "LineItems" child objects from the orders, correct? It doesn't remove the entire order object from the list.

Comment: You could build a new `Order`s collection that only contains the lines you're interested in, but that may or may not be "simpler" than removing the lines you're not interested in, depending on the structure.

Comment: @Ben what are you trying to do? Return only orders and line items whose SKU contains `GRNS`? It could be cheaper to construct new objects with just the items you want instead

Comment: @Raya Yes correct :) Thanks all for this sorry I only just checked now!!

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler & may be more efficient:

```cs
public List<Order> GetGrainOrders() {
    return GetOrdersJson()
            .Select(o => {
                o.LineItems = order.LineItems.Where(i => i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")));
                return o;
            })
            .Where(o => o.LineItems.Count() != 0)
            .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be some minor changes that could at least remove a bit of code...not that it is necessarily "simpler".

```
public List<Order> GetGrainOrders()
{
    var orders = GetOrdersJson()
      .Where(o=>o.LineItems.Any(i=>i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")))
      .ToList();
    orders.ForEach(o => o.LineItems.RemoveAll(i => !i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")));
    return orders;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would add LineItems in your select clause.

```
var orders = GetOrdersJson();
orders = orders.Select(o => new Order
{
    // Assign the other fields you need from Order here
    LineItems = o.LineItems.Where(i => i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")).ToList()
})
    .Where(o => o.LineItems.Any(i => i.Sku.Contains("GRNS")))
    .ToList();

return orders;
```